# How to count colored cells by row in excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a report in excel with three rows with conditional formatting to color map the data. I essentially want the fourth column to output a 1 if at least two cells within the row are green and a 0 if not. Example:any two cells in the row can be green

[image]

So I would like a formula to output a 1 in E4 but 0 for the rest of column E. Is this possible?

Comment: What is the conditional formatting rules.  You need to use those and not the color.  Formula will not note the format of cells.

Comment: For column B it is greater than or equal to 100. For column C it is greater than or equal to 3 hours. For column D it is greater than or equal to 2.

Comment: `=--((B2>=100)+(C2>=TIME(3,0,0))+(D2>=2)>=2)`

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a VBA function like this:

```
Function ColorComparer(rColor1 As Range, rColor2 As Range, rColor3 As Range) As String

Dim vResult As String
Dim greenCounter As Integer

iCol1 = rColor1.Interior.Color
iCol2 = rColor2.Interior.Color
iCol3 = rColor3.Interior.Color
green = RGB(0, 255, 0)
greenCounter = 0


If iCol1 = green Then
    greenCounter = greenCounter + 1
End If

If iCol2 = green Then
    greenCounter = greenCounter + 1
End If

If iCol3 = green Then
    greenCounter = greenCounter + 1
End If

If greenCounter >= 2 Then
    vResult = 1
Else
    vResult = 0
End If

ColorComparer = vResult

End Function
```

The green color has been set to RGB (0, 255, 0) but you can change to any color you want

**Way to use:**

[image: Only one green]

[image: Two greens]

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options that I can think of:

1. create a formula that aligns with the conditional formatting - this has already been suggested by previous contributors. However, this does not actually check cell colors.
2. use a vba script. This can assess cell colors and can be setup as event driven so it runs automatically upon a new worksheet entry.